# MVC5 DisplayModes - Views get mixed up

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I have a "OperaMini" displaymode, and then a `_Layout.OperaMini.cshtml` layout.

This works okay, until I add Output caching. I use this cache profile:

`<add name="Cache1HourVaryByAll" duration="3600" enabled="true" varyByParam="*" />`

If the first hit on a page is from an OperaMini user agent, then all subsequent requests (regardless of their user agent) get the OperaMini page.

I have tried suggestions listed on this [workitem](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/280), FixedDisplayModes etc but I cant get it to work.

I also use HttpRuntime.Cache for some objects, could this be causing issues?

This was supposed to be fixed in MVC5? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to introduce a (pseudo) Vary-By-DisplayMode mechanism:

### Global.asax:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg.ToLower() == "displaymode")
    {
        var currentDisplayMode = DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CanHandleContext(new HttpContextWrapper(context)));

        return "displayMode=" + currentDisplayMode.DisplayModeId;
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
}
```

### Web.Config:

```
<add name="Cache1HourVaryByAll"
     duration="3600"
     enabled="true"
     varyByParam="*"
     varyByCustom="displaymode" />
```